# Windows Authentication prompting for username and password

Tags: security, iis, permissions, iis-7.5

Scenario: 
 1. I have a website (https://mysite.com) with IIS authentication of basic and I can access all subfolders (https://mysite.com/folder1, https://mysite.com/folder2, and https://mysite.com/folder3)
 2. However when I changed the authentication settings of IIS I can only access https://mysite.com/folder1, with the other 2 folders keeps on prompting for username and password even with the correct credentials.
 3. The site use only php files since it was just handed over to me. And also different user groups are permitted per folder. There are no restrictions in the site (https://mysite.com), just the folders

Things I've done so far
 1. Remove Negotiate as a provider of Windows Authentication and only use NTLM
 2. Mirror folder permissions of folder1 into other folders. I've also checked permissions and nothing has deny access.

IIS version is 7.5

Anonymous Authentication is not an option since I want the site to be secured. Basic Authentication can easily be decoded so username and password are shown when decoded.

I need help to figure what might be the cause of the problems with the other 2 folders since Windows authentication is working fine with folder1

Comment: BTW, I'm just new to the technology so I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give authentication permissions to context level,ii mean for folder1,folder2 and folder3....not to entire website...it will resolve the issue

Comment: you mean the site remains on basic authentication then the other folders will have windows authentication?

Comment: you can specify whatever authentication is required for site...and contexts as well...Just you need to select the site and go to Authentication icon...and same thing for contexts as well